# Solr not returning the results

Tags: solr

In Solr ,I have a field called Code_string and it have a values like 
S102.103.111_1, S102.103.111_2

when I search with "S102.103.111" .it's returning me the zero results.

Any inputs on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nikolay said, String type fields are not analyze by default. But text_general type fields will be analyze. You can just change your field name into Code_string_txt then it will be searchable. Otherwise, define your custom field in conf/schema.xml like this

```
<field name="Code_string" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Comment: Of course, it will works, but `StandardTokenizer` splits example string to two tokens `S102.103.111` and `1`. As I guess @sree problem, special kind of tokenizer that provides tokens like `S102.103.111`, `S102.103` and `S102` might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

String type fields aren't analyzed by default. (Assumes you use `StrField`, also check Solr documentation: [Field Types Included with Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr))

So you need either use a wildcard query: `S102.103.111*` or define your own field type with custom analyzer (Look at [Understanding Analyzers, Tokenizers, and Filters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Understanding+Analyzers,+Tokenizers,+and+Filters)).